# Use relative path with Spring MVC RestTemplate using UriComponentBuilder

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-mvc, url, uri

I have this. I would like to get rid from "http://localhost:8080" and use only relative path like i can do with just sending in restTemlate like

```
restTemplate.postForEntity("/processing/$attribute", data, Sum::class.java).body
```

How can i perform that with UriComponentBuilder? Here's my code:

```
 val builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://localhost:8080/calculation/$attribute")
            .queryParam("name", name)
                .build().encode().toUri()

        return  restTemplate.postForEntity(builder, data, Sum::class.java).body
```

Answer (score 1):

You may (and maybe even want to, in case it won't change) set "general part of path" in RestTemplate params:

```
val restTemplate = RestTemplate().apply {
    uriTemplateHandler = DefaultUriBuilderFactory("http://localhost:8080/calculations")
}
```

Then you can use UriComponentBuilder to set up a relative path:

```
val relativeUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("/processing/")
        .queryParam("name", name)
        .build()
        .toUriString()
```

Finally, you can perform a request like:

```
restTemplate.postForEntity<String>(relativeUri, entity)
```